# How to translate this Curl HTTP into Arduino C++?

Tags: http, curl, arduino

I'm using this [simple ArduinoHttpClient example code](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/blob/master/examples/SimplePost/SimplePost.ino) to send a sample POST request from my Arduino to a publicly accessible URL. It works. I get a legit response.

But now, I want to send a HTTP request from my Arduino code that mimics this curl call to send an email [via MailGun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api):

```
curl \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--user 'api:my-api-key-obtained-from-mailgun-website' \
--data-urlencode from='Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org>' \
--data-urlencode to='Me <myemail@gmail.com>' \
--data-urlencode subject='Hello World1' \
--data-urlencode text='Hello World2' \
"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org/messages"
```

How can I do it? When I intercepted this curl call with a proxy, I see that it is sending these bytes:

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Authorization: Basic XXXXXX-How-Was-This-Token-Acquired??-XXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 183
from=Mailgun%20Sandbox%20%3Cpostmaster%40sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org%3E&to=Me%20%3Cmyemail%40gmail.com%3E&subject=Hello%20World1&text=Hello%20World2
```

It's difficult to recreate that in C++. How is that `Authorization` token acquired? There must be an idiomatic/well-known way to do this.

The MailGun website lists examples snippets from [several languages](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api), but [not C/C++](https://twitter.com/Mail_Gun/status/1249966058284466176).

[image]

Comment: The correct answer was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61209028/1742777) by r_ahlskog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ArduinoHttpClient library the Authorization header is created with `sendBasicAuth`. The example for function `sendBasicAuth` is in [BasicAuthGet example](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/blob/7f36561e0bced5458516066ae09636e119cae0ed/examples/BasicAuthGet/BasicAuthGet.ino#L51) of the library.

`client.sendBasicAuth("username", "password");`

Background: the HTTP header Authorization value of [type Basic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2) is a Base64 encoded concatenation of login and password.