# How to convert this Curl HTTP into Arduino C++?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using this [simple ArduinoHttpClient example code](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/blob/master/examples/SimplePost/SimplePost.ino) to send a sample POST request from my Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2 to a publicly accessible URL. It works. I get a legit response.

But now, I want to send a HTTP request from my Arduino code that mimics this curl call to send an email [via MailGun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api):

```
curl \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--user 'api:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--data-urlencode from='Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org>' \
--data-urlencode to='Me <myemail@gmail.com>' \
--data-urlencode subject='Hello World1' \
--data-urlencode text='Hello World2' \
"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org/messages"
```

How can I do it? When I intercepted this curl call with a proxy, I see that it is sending these bytes:

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Authorization: Basic YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 183
from=Mailgun%20Sandbox%20%3Cpostmaster%40sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org%3E&to=Me%20%3Cmyemail%40gmail.com%3E&subject=Hello%20World1&text=Hello%20World2
```

It's difficult to recreate that in C++. How is that `Authorization` token determined? There must be an idiomatic/well-known way to do this.

The [Mailgun](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/blob/master/examples/SimplePost/SimplePost.ino) website lists examples snippets from several languages, but not C/C++. They told me [today](https://twitter.com/Mail_Gun/status/1249966058284466176) they don't offer code snippets for C/C++.

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: wouldn't the authorization token be obtained from the website?

Comment: I guess so. Please show me how I should obtain it.

Comment: Sign up to their service and get an api access token... ?

Comment: i got the key from the website. thats the one i used in the curl. But the authorization token is different from that key.  it is obtained in realtime by doing some kind of exchange with the website. i dont know the details of that exchange.

Comment: Read the documentation

Comment: Your link to the Arduino example points to the Mailgun documentation. Do you intend to include another link?

Comment: Which Arduino are you using? Some boards can't handle TLS/SSL so Mailgun may need to support HTTP for this to work.

Comment: @BenT I fixed the link. Thank you. I'm using an Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That authorization looks like [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). So it is base64-encoded user:password

If you want to verify try base64 decoding the string and see. Needless to be said that makes it wholly unsuitable for use over HTTP since it would be sending your password in clear text.

Comment: base64-encoding the user:password worked! Thank you.